# Connect to a device attached to remotehost and map to localhost

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy

I have a device on a remote host which connects via IP address (see image below).  For this example, my remote host is named **myremote**, and the device is visible on **myremote** as 192.168.3.15, port 55555.

I would like to connect to this device on my local machine (**localhost**) such that I can access the device directly in the same way.  I've tried connecting with `ssh` to map the port, but I cannot reach the device.

How can I setup the ssh tunnel such that I request connection to the device (192.168.3.15:55555) and can access it on my local machine?  I've tried using `ssh tunnel` but haven't had much success:

```
# executed from command line on localhost
ssh -vvv -N -T -L :55555:192.168.3.15:55555 username@myremote
```

I need to connect from localhost to the device at 192.168.3.15:55555, which is visible only on the remote host.  I can connect fine with ssh, and can make other tunnel operations work (jupyter notebook remote server, for instance).  However, I cannot so far reach the device itself.  Note: the device is connected locally to the remote using an ethernet cable, and cannot be seen on the remotehost's LAN.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

I run successfully this command:

```
ssh -vvv -N -T -L 55555:192.168.3.15:55555 username@myremote
```

maybe you provide us with the output from ssh, when it wont work.

On my connection I get:

```
Authenticated to myremote ([XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:55555 forwarded to remote address 192.168.3.15:55555
```

It can also be, that forwarding is not allowed on the remote ssh host.

Check this on the myremote host for a openssh-server:

```
grep AllowTcpForwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

or the params -a, -j and -k for dropbear

Also keep in mind, that you forward a TCP port - not UDP